# Longer domain name extension and ASP.NET MVC validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

A customer complained about not being able to register to our ASP.NET MVC website because his email is like the following:

```
name.surname@innovation.world
```

Here is the standard ASP.NET MVC `RegisterModel`:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "Email must be valid")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

How do I change the regular expression to take in account these new longer domain name extensions?

Thanks.

Comment: Change the last **4** to **5**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could have figured this out yourself by using a site such as: http://regexr.com/

Saying that, I'm not skilled with regex myself, yet I used the site above to solve your issue. To extend the check you simply need to update the **{2,4}** at the end of the expression. Try **{2,6}**. This works for the 'World' TLD but there might be better regex expressions to use for e-mail checking these days.